# Функциональное тестирование в PHP

Tags: php, юнит-тесты

Можно ли использовать модули Symfony для функционального тестирования вне фреймворка, если да, то где можно почитать, как всё это настроить. Или быть может есть другие хорошие библиотеки для функционального тестирования?

Comment: Symfony использует PHPUnit, соответственно к фреймворку он отношения не имеет. Документация PHPUnit здесь https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Можете посмотреть в сторону фреймворка [Codeception](https://codeception.com/), там есть методы для модульных, функциональных и приёмочных тестов. Устанавливается через composer, как и другие пакеты для php-приложений:

```sh
composer require codeception/codeception --dev
```

Примеры использования есть в документации на [официальном сайте](https://codeception.com/docs/04-FunctionalTests).

Symfony использует для тестирования пакет [PHPUnit Bridge](https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge), который в свою очередь использует PHPUnit, как и написал Ordman в комментариях к вашему вопросу. Вы так же можете установить его через composer и использовать в своём проекте:

```sh
composer require phpunit/phpunit --dev
```

Comment: а в PHPUnit разве есть функциональное тестирование, т.е. вызвать контроллер, получить его ответ, найти в нём форму и отправить её с нужными параметрами? (это как пример)

Comment: Для этого вы можете использовать PHPUnit в связке с [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/).